# rails admin making a dropdown for on option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, belongs-to

Hi im trying to make one of the fields in rails admin show also this is an RoR project now im trying to make a drop down menu that gets the  name from one of the tables that i have made to show it. from the  products the ptype will show the models how can i do this? and thanks

this are the codes

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :ptypes
rails_admin do
edit do
    field :name
    field :ptype, :belongs_to_association
    field :body, :ck_editor
    field :value
    end
    end
end


class Ptype < ActiveRecord::Base 
belongs_to :products
   rails_admin do
     edit do
       field :name
    end 
   end
 end
```

this is the error that shows

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass


Request
Parameters:
{"model_name"=>"product"}
```

also thanks!

Comment: nil:NilClass, Which line and file? There is no [] in these files. You may also try to get someone else to write the question. Its not very easy to understand.